# How to make touchable image with header/footer in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm new to xamarin.forms and am looking for the best way to go about designing a content page with three sections -

1. A header with three icons horizontally aligned. Each icon will have a short text description below it.
2. Middle of the page will have an image that the user can touch. A red square will be plotted where the user touch is.
3. A footer, also with three icons horizontally aligned. Each icon will also have a short text description below it.

The colour of all icons needs to be conditional. The plotted square should only be plotted within the image in the center part of the page. I managed to do a mockup of the touchable canvas in xamarin targetting Android, but am not sure where to start with a xamarin.forms project. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I managed to do a mockup of the touchable canvas in xamarin targetting Android, but am not sure where to start with a xamarin.forms project. Any help much appreciated.

For header and footer you can use [Iconize](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Iconize) for that.

For TouchableImage, you can create a custom control with customRenderer, which leverage your Canvas. You can refer to a similar example from [here](http://www.xrmcoaches.com/2014/06/creating-a-drawing-app-using-xamarin-forms/) for details.